# Does Bender from Futurama sound like a non-American?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, accent

Robot [Bender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_(Futurama)) is one of the main characters in the animated television series 'Futurama'.

[Bender — Best moments](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sNMHdaJx5c) (5 minute video).

- Does Bender speak ‘proper’ American English? Does he have an American accent?
- Are there any features in Bender's speech which suggest that English is not his native tongue?

I did not provide any dialogue or script excerpts because I am only interested in the character's pronunciation and if native speakers consider him foreign-sounding. Does he?

Comment: I believe OP is asking whether "Bender" (the robot on Futurama) speaks proper "American English" or if he has an accent.  Further he wishes to know whether Bender uses proper grammar or whether he makes mistakes.

Comment: To me (AmE) he uses fine grammar but his accent is a slightly over-exaggerated mid-Western.  Not something I'd choose to model if I was trying to learn to speak with an American accent.

Comment: There is something weird about his accent, but I've never stopped to wonder what.

Comment: If by *foreigner* you mean a generic *non-American* or a specific nationality, please edit your title to say so. To non-Americans (e.g. Australian, British, Canadian, Dutch, Ecuadorian, French, German, ...), Americans *are* foreigners. To Americans, non-Americans are foreigners. So trivially, *everyone* speaks like a foreigner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To answer your questions as simply as possible:

> Does Bender speak ‘proper’ American English? Does he have an American accent?

Yeah. Pretty much.

> Are there any features in Bender's speech which suggest that English is not his native tongue?

No. Not really.

---

### Further comments that you might find helpful:

- Benders voice is fairly distinctive. It is probably the *timbre* that you are picking up on.
- The voice is put on. It's not how the voice-over artist naturally sounds. For instance:
- The voice-over artist also does the voice of *Adventure Time* character *Jake The Dog*.
- Bender, as a character, often throws his voice to immitate various accents and personas.